# KVM module not load after installing cloudstack-agent

Tags: centos, kvm-virtualization, cloudstack

I follow this guide to install CloudStack and KVM:

https://docs.cloudstack.apache.org/projects/cloudstack-installation/en/latest/qig.html#kvm-setup-and-installation

Everything went well but after install cloudstack-agent:

```
# yum -y install cloudstack-agent
```

and do the configuration as the guide, I can't see any result when check if KVM is running OK on my machine:

```
# lsmod | grep kvm
```

I don't know the reason.

When I check cloudstack-agent status:

```
# service cloudstack-agent status
cloudstack-agent dead but subsys locked
```

The log is:

```
# tail /var/log/cloudstack/agent/agent.log
...
2017-04-18 12:13:14,205 ERROR [kvm.storage.LibvirtStorageAdaptor] (Agent-Handler-1:null) (logid:) org.libvirt.LibvirtException: XML error: missing pool source name element
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This guide only provides steps to install and configure cloudstack-agent on KVM server.

You need to install KVM first on this server:

```
# yum install kvm qemu-kvm python-virtinst libvirt libvirt-python libguestfs-tools
```

After installing these packages, start libvirt service and check if kvm is working fine:

```
# lsmod | grep kvm
```

Comment: After I installed those packages, there also nothing when run `lsmod | grep kvm`. OS: CentOS 6.8

Comment: This because I am using vagrant.

Comment: In that case, you won't be able to use kvm. Please check if cpu has vmx or svm flag which is required for kvm. `egrep ‘(vmx|svm)’ /proc/cpuinfo`

Comment: Yes, I checked that. There aren't.